# Difference between "ich bin" and "bin ich"

Tags: usage

I am a complete newbie in German. It is given **ich bin** means **I am**. Also **bin ich** means **I am**. Why is this?

Comment: You are mistaken, *bin ich* means the same as English *am I*. Usually, a question about yourself follows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual (ordinary, unmarked) order is "Ich bin...". E.g.

> Ich bin Kaminfeger.
>
> Ich bin sturzbesoffen.
>
> Ich bin im Urlaub gewesen.

However, there are situations where word order is the other way round.

This is, first, **in questions**:

> Bin ich fertig?
>
> Bin ich heute schon auf dem Dachboden gewesen?
>
> Bin ich denn blöd?
>
> Laust mich denn ein Affe?

(Sentences with other verbs than "sein" are added in order to demonstrate that this works with all verbs.)

Second, inverse word oder may carry a meaning like "if" or "when" or "in case of" - **a conditional clause**. This requires the verb being the very first element:

> Bin ich in deiner Nähe, so bleibt die Zeit für mich stehen.
>
> Bin ich erst einmal reich, mache ich lauter Dinge, die anderen nützen und der Welt ein Segen sind.
>
> Bleibe ich jedoch arm, dann sind meine Kräfte beschränkt.
>
> Wär' ich ein tapfres Schneiderlein, tät' ich des Königs Tochter frei'n.

Meaning "When I am near to you" (Sentence 1), or "Once I have become rich" or "When I am rich" (Sentence 2). This, however, is a somewhat poetical way of speaking. You will not hear that often it in everyday language. (Accordingly the topic of the sample sentences is a little bit more poetic here.)

Third, as commenter Carsten correctly noted, inverse word oder appears when a *Prädikativum* (Prädikatsnomen) is put on first position, which can be done for **emphasis**:

> Kaminfeger bin ich, nicht Zaubermeister!
>
> Groß sind die Werke des Herrn, klein ist der Menschen Gemüt.
>
> Spaghetti will ich essen, nicht Sauerkraut.
>
> Verflucht soll er sein! In der Hölle soll er schmoren!

This again may be met in more elaborate forms of expression such as poetry, drama, verse etc.

But there are also situations in everyday life where this word oder may be used without being so evidently "special" (examples include some contributed by commenter Stephie):

> Heute bin ich zuhause.
>
> Ohne Kaffee bin ich zu nichts zu gebrauchen.
>
> Morgen wird das Wetter besser.
>
> Am Ende hast du Recht.

In these examples, too, some element of the sentence different from the subject is put in first position for emphasis, and thus the word order gets inversed. However, opposed to the first group, in these sentences emphasis by first position seems to be the natural thing to do, and such sentences are common in everyday language.

Comment: Isn't the question referring to the following situation: Bist du Christian? Bin ich! I guess this might come from the fact that "Das" is implicit? Like, das bin ich?

Comment: The third case is way less unusual than you are presenting it here. Just think of examples like “Heute bin ich zuhause.” or “Ohne Kaffee bin ich zu nichts zu gebrauchen.”.

Comment: @Stephie  - Hm. Yes. You are right.

Comment: I think tnat in this (good) answer, the right order would be the last examples at the top or second place (I am almost sure the OP wanted to know that).

Answer (score 3):

There are two cases. In one case (question) "Bin ich" means "am I." In the other case, when the words are inverted in a statement, they mean "I am."

In the question case, the inversion of the words creates the question. "Bin ich hier?" Am I here?

So why would the words be inverted in a statement? Because, in German, the verb is *always* in the second position (except for questions and subordinating conjunctions). On the other hand, it is common in German to switch the subject and the object around the verb, putting the object in the first position, and the subject in the third.

So, "Ich bin hier," means the same as "Hier bin ich." Which means "I am here."

In English, if you put "Here" in the first position, the sentence would be "Here I am." But in German, the construction is "X am Y "or "Y am X," so when you put "Hier" in the first slot, the "ich" follows (rather than precedes), "bin."